# ODIN : Binary size is too large

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, odin

Device Name : gt5note10lte/SM-P555/Samsung Galaxy Tab A
TWRP Source : https://github.com/minimal-manifest-twrp/platform_manifest_twrp_omni
Android version : 10

I am trying to build TWRP for my device. The stock ROM is running on Android 7.1.1.
When I am trying to flash the recovery.img file using ODIN, the error "ODIN: Binary size is too large : recovery" is displayed in Download mode. Anyone faced this issue ?

From the description, I understand that the recovery partition is small. What is the best way to move forward ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why? TWRP already exists for the device [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-twrp-3-1-0-1-galaxy-tab-a-sm-t350-355-357-550-555-sm-p350-355-550-555.3426560/).

Comment: the version that is available for my device is 3.0.2.1 (I think it is based on android 7 too) and I am trying to upgrade my device to Android 10. So, trying to move to latest version too.

Comment: TWRP version isn't strongly tied to Android version. The 10 branch is for devices *shipping* with Android 10+, AFAIK. That said, 3.0.x is a lil old in terms of features, so try the 9 branch.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, I had that doubt too. I have also tried the twrp-7.1 from this link which generates the same error too. https://github.com/EngMoPro/platform_manifest_twrp_omni

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount storage on twrp-3.5.2\_9-0](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239131/unable-to-mount-storage-on-twrp-3-5-2-9-0)