# Unable to mount storage on twrp-3.5.2_9-0

Tags: twrp, storage

My device is gt5note10lte (SM-P555) and running on Samsung stock 7.1.1.

I have compiled the twrp in 7.1 version but unable to get the storage mounted.

Device tree : https://github.com/psuryatej4android/twrp_device_samsung_gt5note10lte

TWRP Sources : https://github.com/EngMoPro/platform_manifest_twrp_omni

I think it is to do with some permissions. Please refer to the following video to see the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxJ6ry5iHDQ

I have tried changing twrp.fstab, init*.rc,. Also, tried the suggestions from youtube videos.but no luck

XDA request link : https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-mount-storage-on-twrp-3-5-2_9-0.4300059/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are missing symlinks. resolve it from boot mode with `realpath` and use it in fstab. also have a look into TWRP 3.0.2 fstab init.rc

Comment: Tried, still not successful. will update once able to make it work

Comment: give example how did you resolve symlink and how did you update fstab